# rundeck sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: rundeck

I am working on rundeck server. where i added remote node & try to run the script on remote node.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/os-release
sed -i  '/#DNS=/c DNS=8.8.8.8' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf && sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

when i run this job, its stuck & after killing the job manually.

**output**

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
Failed: Interrupted: Connection was interrupted
[sudo] password for anas:
```

**resource.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>

 <node name="node-1" always-set-pty="true" description="Rundeck server node" tags="" hostname="64.23.123.189" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.15.0-189-generic" sudo-command-enabled="true" sudo-command-pattern="^sudo .+? sudo .*$" sudo-password-option="option.sudoPassword"  username="anas" ssh-authentication="password" ssh-password-storage-path="keys/Proxmox/88.password"/>

</project>
```

I also tried many other attributes like:

```
sudo-prompt-pattern="^.*password.*"  

sudo-password-option="option.sudoPassword"  

sudo-command-pattern="^sudo .+? sudo .*$"  

sudo-command-enabled="true"  

always-set-pty="true" 

sudo2-command-enabled="true" 

sudo2-command-pattern="^sudo .+? sudo .*$"
```

Rundeck version

```
Rundeck 4.7.0
```

Can anyone explain, what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your scenario and your issue. Checking your model source entry, I'm sure that you want to use an option as a password to authenticate and execute the `sudo` commands, let me share a node entry and job definition example:

Node definition example (tested on remote Ubuntu 22.04 and Rocky Linux 8 servers):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node name="ubuntu" 
  description="ubuntu" 
  tags="prod" 
  hostname="192.168.56.12" 
  osArch="amd64" 
  osFamily="unix" 
  osName="Linux" 
  osVersion="5.11.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP" 
  always-set-pty="true"
  username="vagrant" 
  ssh-authentication="password" 
  ssh-password-storage-path="keys/sudopasswd"
  sudo-command-enabled="true" 
  sudo-command-pattern="^sudo$"
  sudo-prompt-pattern="^\[sudo\] password for .+: .*"
  sudo-password-option="option.sudoPassword" />
</project>
```

As you see, the `sudo-command-pattern` is different and you need to add the `sudo-prompt-pattern` attribute which "receives" the `sudo` prompt to put the password automatically.

Job Definition Example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 57262967-00f1-4e5e-b872-57ace765daee
  loglevel: INFO
  name: TestSUDO
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'name: ubuntu '
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: sudoPassword
    required: true
    secure: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: 'first test: using the command step'
      exec: sudo whoami
    - description: 'second test: on script step'
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |
        sudo whoami
      scriptInterpreter: sudo /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: sequential
  uuid: 57262967-00f1-4e5e-b872-57ace765daee
```

Some things to consider:

1. The option named in the `sudo-password-option` node entry (`sudoPassword` on the job), must be a [Secure Remote Authentication](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#secure-remote-authentication-options) Option.
2. The `sudo` attributes work flawlessly on command steps, that's a little different on script steps (next point).
3. On Script steps (like your use-case), it needs to define the `sudo` command in the Invocation String textbox (Edit your job > Go to your script step > click on the Advanced link > Invocation string), in my case, I used `sudo /bin/bash` with `.sh` as File Extension.

Check the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHFEX.jpg).